# Add user in SQL Server Management Studio 2017

Tags: sql-server, authentication

I try (for the first time) to create a user account on my SQL Azure database.
I have read in some blogs that I have to create these command lines

```
CREATE LOGIN login_name WITH PASSWORD = 'strong_password';
CREATE USER 'user_name' FOR LOGIN 'login_name';
```

And then

```
USE [Database];
GO
GRANT CONNECT TO login_name;
```

But, when I try to connect with this new account on my database, I have the message error 916
The server principal "login_name is not able to access the database "master" under the current security context.

I don't understand because the don't create my new user for the master but for a specific database in my SQL Azure environment (I have 5 databases in my SQL Azure by the way)

If you have any idea to help me, thanks in advance

Comment: You don't have the login mapped to a specific Database so it defaulted to master. Please read the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017&tabs=sqlserver)

Comment: From the docs _DEFAULT_DATABASE =database
Specifies the default database to be assigned to the login. If this option is not included, the default database is set to master._ it seems that this your issue.

Answer (score 1):

When first logging in, unless a database is specified in the connection string, a login connects to its default database. If the database is not specified in the CREATE LOGIN statement, the system default of `master` is used.

To fix this, use this for your CREATE LOGIN:

```
CREATE LOGIN login_name WITH PASSWORD = 'strong_password',
      DEFAULT_DATABASE = MyDatabase;
```